# AWS LAMBDA using java sdk SES Client times out

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I have a very basic lambda function to send email
The Code hangs on creating SES Client .i put logs before and after this statement of creating client .

```
AmazonSimpleEmailService client = AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
          .withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(false)).build();
```

i also tried

```
AmazonSimpleEmailService client = AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).build();
```

The lambda function assumes IAM role with **AmazonSESFullAccess** , any one could point to resolution why do i get timeout here trying to initiate client ?

Comment: Did you place your Lambda function inside a VPC?

Comment: Are you configuring a very short timeout (< ~10s) and or a very small amount of memory (< ~512 MiB)?

Comment: You guys gave a good hint thanks, i tried NO VPC , increased timeout from 3 to 10 seconds, and increased mem to 960MB , it worked. i was guessing defaults should work... BUt now i get 
`code`  Unable to load credentials from service endpointEND `code`

Comment: IF my Lambda is using a Role that has policy allowing FullSESAccess ,
how do i build client ? or do i always have to use secret keys for programatic execution ?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue of Credentials creation times out as suggested in reply i tried

*NO VPC , increased timeout from default 3 to 10 seconds, and increased mem to 960MB*

Creating Service sdk client in java use **EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider()** for **LAMBDA**  that fixed the Client Initialisation problem of for EC2 use **InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(true)**

> Unable to load credentials from service endpoint

AmazonSimpleEmailService client =

AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
              .withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider()).build();

thanks a lot for help ...